# How to use 'Choice Router' in Anypoint studio for this scenario?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have used RAML file to generate flows through APIKit router. I have example.json for example response.
My RAML code is:

```
 #%RAML 0.8
 ---
 title: TestEmployee API
 version: v1

 /employee:
  get:
 queryParameters:
  id:
    enum: [1,2,3,4]
    required: true
    type: string
    description: Employee id
   name:
    enum: [Charles,John,Neha,Shruti]
    required: true
    type: string
    description: Employee_name
   responses:
   200:
    body:
      application/json:
        example: !include example.json
```

JSON example response is :

```
 [
 {
 "id": 1,
 "name":"Charles",
 "code": "C1ENU00",
 "dateofjoining":"2019/06/24",
 "domain":"ENU",
 "address":"Hyderabad",
 "phone": 9865458936,
 "program": "WASE"
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "name":"John",
 "code": "C2DIG00",
 "dateofjoining":"2019/06/24",
 "domain":"DIGITAL",
 "address":"Chennai",
 "phone": 9756359864,
 "program": "ELITE"
 }
```

I want to use a choice router to appropriately call flow when 'id' and 'name' matches. Like in query params if the user enters 'id=1&name=Charles' then only choice router would call main flow, else it should call default one. Initially, the payload is set to 'example JSON response' body. Please guide me achieving this.

Here are flows for reference. [image: Flows]

Comment: You can simply define id and name in set Variable, compare query params with set variables `==`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `when` `expression` attribute in your choice router to a Dataweave expression matching your use case. You can access queryParams by name using attributes.queryParams.YOUR-QUERY-PARAM-NAME syntax:

```
#[attributes.queryParams.id=='1' and attributes.queryParams.name=='Charles']
```

Then add a when scope for every route you need and an optional otherwise for a default route:

```
<choice>
    <when
        expression="#[attributes.queryParams.id=='1' and attributes.queryParams.name=='Charles']">
        <flow-ref name="some-flow" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <flow-ref name="some-other-flow" />
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

For Mule 3 use:

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.id == '1' &amp;&amp; message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name =='Charles']
```